# Bibliography with some specific entries, independently of the global bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have a long document with a (single) bibliography at the end. For some reason, at some point in the middle I cite 3 sources and I need to typeset their bibliography entries right there on the spot. How can I do that?

I'm using `bibtex`, but not `biblatex`. (For now.)

I'll also mention that those happen to be the only citations in a certain `\chapter*`, so a chapter-bibliography-based solution is relevant, though it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

egreg's early solution, with several tweaks/ideas/suggestions by egreg:

- Supporting 'alpha' style (and probably many others unlike plain).
- Allowing the command to be used after the main bibliography.
- A somewhat ugly hack supporting cite keys being substrings of each other.

‌

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\partialcites}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\etalchar\@undefined
  \def\thebibliography##1{\begin{itemize}}%
  \def\endthebibliography{\end{itemize}}%
  % for plain style
  %\def\bibitem##1##2\par{\IfSubStr{#1}{##1}{\item[\cite{##1}]##2}{}}%
  \def\bibitem[##1]##2##3\par{\IfSubStr{,#1,}{,##2,}{\item[\cite{##2}]##3}{}}%
  \@input{\jobname.bbl}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\partialcites{AB,CD}

Now for a real cite. \cite{AB}. \cite{CD}.

%\nocite{*}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course such a definition will *not* work (the second \partialcites should be `\partialcites@inner`). However, it's sufficient to add the commas around the first argument to `\IfSubStr`.

Comment: @egreg: Umm, yeah, I mis-copy-pasted. But - how would it be sufficient to add the commas around the first arg to `\IfSubStr`? The first and last keys are not surrounded by commas...

Comment: In your macros, the first argument to `\IfSubStr` is `#1`, which is the argument to `\partialcites@inner`, which is just the argument to `\partialcites` with initial and final commas added. So it's sufficient to say `\IfSubStr{,#1,}...`, without `\partialcites@inner`, isn't it? See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works if the cited sources appear also in the final bibliography; they will appear only when the complete bibliography has been produced, as we read the same `.bbl` file.

The command `\partialcites` takes as first argument the widest label (I'm afraid it would be quite difficult to compute it automatically) and as second argument the citation keys you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\partialcites}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\etalchar\@undefined
  \def\thebibliography##1{%
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
       \leftmargin\labelwidth
       \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
       \@openbib@code
       \usecounter{enumiv}%
       \let\p@enumiv\@empty
       \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
     \sloppy
     \clubpenalty4000
     \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
     \widowpenalty4000%
     \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  }
  \let\endthebibliography\endlist
  \def\bibitem[##1]##2##3\par{\IfSubStr{,#2,}{,##2,}{\item[\cite{##2}]##3}{}}%
  \@input{\jobname.bbl}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\partialcites{AFKS00}{key1,key2}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Limitation: the argument to `\partialcites` must have no spaces around the commas. The problem of substrings is actually very easy to solve.

Comment: I'm using the `alpha` bibliography style, so my entries look like `\bibitem[AFKS00]{AFKS}`, newline, `Noga Alon, Eldar Fischer etc. etc.`

Comment: Also, this needs to work with hyperref... well, trying to work on it a bit myself.

Comment: This will work with hyperref. The "short bibliography" items will link to the final one, as we use `\cite` to typeset the label.

Comment: Umm, I didn't say all my entries had AFKS00 at the beginning... I just tweaked your previous answer to have `\bibitem[##1]##2##3 etc.` and that worked. Why the complication?

Comment: The first argument to `\partialcites` is just the *largest* label: with the previous solution you won't get a good alignment when the labels are wide.

Comment: Actually for my specific use I remove the citation key altogether. But ok.

Comment: Ok, the limitation is proving to be a problem as well.. I have some ABC2001 and ABC2001b pairs. See the tweak in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `bibentry.sty`, it's designed to do exactly what you want.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @percusse, what's wrong with my answer? It tells the OP how to solve the problem. There's no need to reinvent the wheel. Did I miss something in the problem that `bibentry.sty` does not handle straightforwardly?

Comment: The problem is precisely that. If you check the answers on this site, rarely you would see one-liner pointers. Suppose I don't know what `bibentry.sty` is or where it is located, it's a style file is it on CTAN? I found it then what? Note also that this site is closely tracked by Google and many other not-so-proficient TeXers are also reading these stuff. Your answer can be revived by giving a simple demostration. This will also ensure that the solution is a tested one, just see the ones above. Thus, as it is your answer is a comment  (more of a pointer) but not an answer.